# How do I sort taking greater than and less than into consideration?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to have a sort on two strings take the > and < symbols into consideration. So, for example, the sort might look like

```
<20
<40
<100
0.1
10
1,000,000.75
>100
>1,000
```

So basically all the strings with < are first, followed by a normal sort, followed by all numbers with a > symbol. I'd also like the sort to respect the exact order shown (e.g. >100 appears before >1,000 when sorted low to high)

Here is my code that works without the  symbols (sorting all rows in a table):

```
if ($this.hasClass('sort-mixed')) {
  sort_func = sort_mixed;
}
$rows.sort(sort_func);

function sort_mixed(a, b) {

  var val_a = $(a).children().eq(column_index).text();
  var val_b = $(b).children().eq(column_index).text();

  val_a = Number(val_a.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));
  val_b = Number(val_b.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));  

  if(val_a > val_b) {
    return 1 * sort_direction;
  }
  if(val_a < val_b) {
    return -1 * sort_direction;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort with a single comparator function:

```
const order = { regular: 1, reverse: -1 };
let sortOrder = order.regular;
let strings = ['0.1', '1,000,000.75', '10', '<100', '<20', '<40', '>1,000', '>100'];

function compare(a, b) {
   function toNum(str) { return +str.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''); }
   function range(str) { return { '<': -1, '>': 1 }[str[0]] || 0; }
   const rangeA = range(a);
   const rangeB = range(b);
   const score = rangeA === rangeB ? toNum(a) - toNum(b) : rangeA - rangeB;
   return score * sortOrder;
   }

strings.sort(compare);
```

The function `range()` checks if the string starts with a `'<'` or `'>'` and sets a value that is used for sorting if the strings have different ranges.  Otherwise, the strings are converted to numbers and simply sorted as numbers.

With the example input data, the resulting `strings` array is:

```
["<20", "<40", "<100", "0.1", "10", "1,000,000.75", ">100", ">1,000"]
```

Fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/fxgt4uzm

*Edited:*
Added `sortOrder`.

Comment: This plugged right in (well except I had to change (a) to (val_a) and (b) to (val_b), except, can you please account for my sort_direction setting?

Comment: @Webdrips I just added the `reverseSort` option.  If you prefer to have a separate reverse comparator function, check out:
https://jsfiddle.net/eyb7t3jz/5

Comment: Dem P. I was able to get it to work using something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is not a complete solution but enough to get you started. We'll break the array into multiple parts, sort each part, then put the array back together.

```js
function toNumber(s) {
  return +s.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
}
var arr = [
  '<20',
  '>1,000',
  '1,000,000.75',
  '<40',
  '0.1',
  '10',
  '<100',
  '>100'
];
var lt = arr
  .filter(s => s.startsWith('<'))
  .map(s => s.slice(1))
  .map(toNumber)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .map(n => '<' + n);
var eq = arr
  .filter(s => !s.startsWith('>') && !s.startsWith('<'))
  .map(toNumber)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .map(n => '' + n);
var gt = arr.filter(s => s.startsWith('>'))
  .map(s => s.slice(1))
  .map(toNumber)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .map(n => '>' + n);
console.log([].concat(lt, eq, gt));
```

Outputs:

```
["<20", "<40", "<100", "0.1", "10", "1000000.75", ">100", ">1000"]
```

Comment: You have a typo, `filter(s => !s.startsWith('>') && !s.startsWith('>'))` is supposed to be `filter(s => !s.startsWith('>') && !s.startsWith('<'))`

Comment: Actually, `.map(s => s.slice(1))` is not necessary since you will drop `"<"` or `">"` in `toNumber`

Comment: I was able to get this working by itself, thanks, but I was kinda hoping to have the answer be part of the sort function I posted so we can account for sort high to low or low to high based on a button clicked in the table. Sorry I'm still not super skilled with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Composition approach

```
// Sort function maker
// - create a sort fn based on two compare fns
//   {f}= primary
//   {g}= secondary
const sort = (f, g) => (a, b) => f(a,b) || g(a,b)

// Compare function maker
// - create a compare fn based on a weighting fn, {w}
const cmp_asc_of = (w) => (a, b) => w(a) - w(b)
const cmp_desc_of = (w) => (a, b) => w(b) - w(a)

// Weighting function
// - weight a given string, {string}, returns a number
const weight_op = (string) => ..
const weight_num = (string) => ..

// Then, create sort functions
const asc  = sort(cmp_asc_of(weight_op), cmp_asc_of(weight_num))
const desc = sort(cmp_asc_of(weight_op), cmp_desc_of(weight_num))

// Usage
array.sort(asc)
array.sort(desc)
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/fcx40vef/)

For your case..

```
..
function sort_mixed(a, b) {
  var val_a = ..
  var val_b = ..
  return isHighToLow ? desc(val_a, val_b) : asc(val_a, val_b)
```